# Java-Eclipse-WebDriver: Touch & Scroll Implementation - Automated Testing

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, selenium

How can I implement a method to **touch and slide/scroll** in Eclipse, using Java programming language?

Basically, I have to find a specific element (in my case, the slider that I want to touch and scroll) and change the value by sliding/scrolling up & down.

Thank you!

Comment: If you're using `Webdriver` I would guess that you could achieve this with the `Actions()` class. That is of course, if click events are handled in the way that a touch event would be?

Answer (score 0):

[**IPhoneDriver**](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/iphone/IPhoneDriver.html) dont provide out of the box support for touch events still you can achieve it using jQuery

```
/**
* Simulate the swipe action. This will swipe from right to left from the position of the element
* @param elementToSwipe
*/
public void swipeLeft(String elementToSwipe){
String javascriptToExecute = “window.jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(“
+ getElementXPosition(elementToSwipe) + “,”
+ getElementYPosition(elementToSwipe) + “))”+SWIPELEFT;
executeScript(javascriptToExecute);
}

/**
* Simulate the swipe action. This will swipe from left to right from the position of the element
* @param elementToSwipe
*/
public void swipeRight(String elementToSwipe){
String javascriptToExecute = “window.jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(“
+ getElementXPosition(elementToSwipe) + “,”
+ getElementYPosition(elementToSwipe) + “))”+SWIPERIGHT;
executeScript(javascriptToExecute);
}
```

[**Source**](http://seleniumgrid.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-to-simulate-touch-actions-using-webdriver-in-iphone-or-ipad/)